# How can I do a custom order in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, how do I define a custom sorting order.

```
ID  Language    Text
0   ENU         a
0   JPN         b
0   DAN         c       
1   ENU         d
1   JPN         e
1   DAN         f
2   etc...
```

here I want to return all rows sorted by Language in this order: Language = ENU comes first, then JPN and lastly DAN.

Is this even possible?

I would like to order by language, in this order: ENU, JPN, DNA, and so on: ENU, JPN, DNA,ENU,JPN, DAN,ENU, JPN, DAN

NOT: ENU,ENU,ENU,JPN,JPN,JPN,DAN,DAN,DAN

Comment: is each id having all three languages?

Answer (score 1):

You basically need 2 levels of sort. I am using arrays to arrange the languages in the order I want and then `array_position` to assign every language an index based on which they will be sorted. You can achieve the same using either a `case expression` or `decode`. To make sure the languages don't repeat within the same id, we use `row_number`. You can comment out the the `row_number()` line if that's not a requirement

```
with cte (id, lang) as

(select 0,'JPN' union all 
 select 0,'ENU' union all 
 select 0,'DAN' union all 
 select 0,'ENU' union all 
 select 0,'JPN' union all
 select 0,'DAN' union all
 select 1,'JPN' union all 
 select 1,'ENU' union all 
 select 1,'DAN' union all 
 select 1,'ENU' union all 
 select 1,'JPN' union all
 select 1,'DAN')

select * 
from cte
order by id,
         row_number() over (partition by id, array_position(lang::variant,['ENU','JPN','DAN']) order by lang), --in case you want languages to not repeat within each id
         array_position(lang::variant,['ENU','JPN','DAN'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked array_position solution of Phil Coulson. It's also possible to use DECODE:

```
create or replace table mydata ( ID number,  Language varchar,   Text varchar )
as select * from values 
(0,   'JPN'   ,   'b'),
(0,   'DAN'   ,    'c'  ),     
(0,   'ENU'   ,    'a'),
(1 ,  'JPN'   ,     'e'),
(1 ,  'ENU'   ,     'd'),
(1 ,  'DAN'  ,      'f');

select * from
mydata order by ID, DECODE(Language,'ENU',0,'JPN',1,'DAN',2 );


+----+----------+------+
| ID | LANGUAGE | TEXT |
+----+----------+------+
|  0 | ENU      | a    |
|  0 | JPN      | b    |
|  0 | DAN      | c    |
|  1 | ENU      | d    |
|  1 | JPN      | e    |
|  1 | DAN      | f    |
+----+----------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not to say other answers are wrong.
But here's yet another not using ANSI SQL 'CASE':

```
SELECT * FROM "Example"
ORDER BY
    CASE "Language" WHEN 'ENU' THEN 1
        WHEN 'JPN' THEN 2
        WHEN 'DAN' THEN 3
        ELSE 4 END
    ,"Language";
```

Notice the `"Language"` code is used as a disambiguation for 'other' languages not specified.

It's good defensive programming when dealing with `CASE` to deal with `ELSE`.

The ultimate most flexible answer is to have a table with a collation order for languages in it.

Collation order columns are common in many applications.
I've seen them for things like multiple parties to a contract who should appear in a specified order to (of course) the positional order of columns in a table of metadata.